# Return grouped and annotated objects as json in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

How can I return a grouped queryset as json?

I've tried

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    q = self.model.objects.values('id').annotate(sum_amount=Sum('amount')).order_by('sum_amount')
    json_dict = [obj for obj in q]
    return self.render_json_response(json_dict)
```

but it results in

```
[
  {
    "id": 13,
    "sum_amount": "200.00"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "sum_amount": "300.00"
  },
]
```

The output should be an array as this:

```
[
  [
    13, "200.00"
  ],
  [
    3, "300.00"
  ],
]
```

It seems to work with

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    q = self.model.objects.all()
    json_dict = [[obj.id, obj.amount] for obj in q]
    return self.render_json_response(json_dict)
```

but it is not grouped.

Answer (score 0):

Replace values by values_list

`self.model.objects.values_list('id').annotate(sum_amount=Sum('amount')).order_by('sum_amount')`